# Play Games for Unity achievement is broken

Tags: unity, google-play, google-play-services

There was a huge issue a few months ago while integrating with Firebase. The authentication always failed, and all the features were broken.

Somehow I fixed the authentication by adding an app signing certificate in Google Cloud OAuth, but the achievement system is still broken and not coming back.

There are two types of this issue. The first issue is just not working at all. I added achievement in the last update, and it's already been two months, but no man who achieved it. Many of my players already satisfied the condition, but no one achieved it in my Google Play Console.

The second issue is that they consistently watch the same unlocking achievement popup every time they play it. Afaik, if the user already achieved the achievement, it should be just ignored. It was, but after the firebase incident, it's broken.

Whether it's the first or the second case, the new achievement has not been cleared at all, so it's clear that it's completely broken in my case.

I already added my app signing and uploading SHA-1 in my Google Cloud project. Authentication and Saved Games are works, but achievement isn't. What am I missing?

Using Unity 2019.4.31f and Play Games for Unity 0.10.14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding a new credential in Google Play Console that exists in Google Cloud Project.